# Django: Receive data from form once

Tags: django

I don't know exactly how to name this question, but this is my problem. I have a calendar which behavior depends on get parameters. I have 2 basics GET params: month and year so it renders calendar for specific year and month.

My problem:
I need option to change month to next / previous. I can easily do that with JS using ajax, but now I want it to work for non-JS users as well.

I tried:
next_month / prev_moth GET param so I render calendar depending on that params, but here's the problem with this approach: if user refresh page, wrong calendar is rendered because refreshing is just repeating request so params will be saved so if user refresh page 10 times he will get calendar from 10 months before (if there is prev_month get param). I can't remove get params because QueryDict is immutable.

Comment: Show the code you have written. How do you find out what month a user wants from the `prev_month` GET parameter? **Note**: If your problem is with code you have written it is best to show the code in your question in the form of a [mre].

Comment: month and year are GET params, if they are not provided, current month is used in calendar. in calendar.html there is get form for this data. edit: i will send code soon